# Ubuntu shows refresh rate as 120hz but in fact its not more than 60hz

Tags: 18.04, laptop, screen, gpu

I set the refresh rate to 120 hertz in Displays settings. I also enabled Composite in CompizConfig Settings Manager and disabled Detect Refresh Rate.

Although it looks OK it actually is not. I used 120 hertz in windows for a long time so I can feel its not 120 hertz. Its actually is 60 hertz. And I want to feel 120 hertz in ubuntu too.

My Laptop's specs (Monster Tulpar T7 v16)

- Intel i7 8750H (UHD630 Graphics)
- Nvidia GeForce 1060 6GB Mobile

screenshot from **Displays** setting *(none of the settings didn't affect on actual refresh rate)*
[Image of Displays setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTfID.png)

screenshot from **CompizConfig Settings Manager** (I actually couldn't figure out how to use it. I only activated Enable Composite. Nothing more in the app. And no visual effect like black screen of refresh monitor setting showed up.)
[Image of CompizConfig Settings Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l83sp.png)

**xrandr** output:

```
    $ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 381mm x 214mm
   1920x1080    120.00*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     84.94    74.89    69.88    59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     85.00    74.76    70.00    59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     85.02    75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      85.00    60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864     100.00    85.06    85.00    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      85.00    75.05    60.04    85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   1024x768i     86.96  
   960x720       85.00    75.00    60.00  
   928x696       75.00    60.05  
   896x672       75.05    60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       85.00    75.00    70.00    65.00    60.00    85.14    72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       85.02    74.96    69.88    60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       85.08    74.76    70.06    59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       85.02    75.02    60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       85.09    60.00    85.01    72.81    75.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   720x400       85.04  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98    85.08  
   576x432      100.11    85.15    85.09    75.00    75.00    70.00    60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   640x350       85.08  
   512x384       85.00    75.03    70.07    60.00  
   512x384i      87.06  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   416x312       74.66  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       85.27    72.19    75.12    60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       85.18    72.81    75.00    60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   360x200       85.04  
   320x200       85.27  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
   320x175       85.27  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

and **sudo lshw -C display** output.

```
    sudo lshw -C display
[sudo] password for ataberkw: 
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP106M [GeForce GTX 1060 Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:7e000000-7effffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:7f000000-7f07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:130 memory:7d000000-7dffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

**--UPDATE--**
I feel like my GUI rendering by the CPU. When I shake a window, intel-gpu-overlay shows cpu usage a big increase but 0 gpu usage.
[click to see the usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0MTZ.png)
Normally cpu usage is around 20%, but when I start to shake a window, it jumps over 100%.

**--UPDATE2--**
I gave up for now with unsuccessful 60hz refresh rate on ubuntu 18.04 @ 20.x Linux kernel.

Comment: High Refresh Rate is a quite new technology and linux is always late in support new techs... First of all, which softwares version are you using?

Comment: @mattia.b89 I didn't get which software version do you need. Here is some info about my system uname -a Linux Tulpar 4.20.0-042000-generic #201812232030 SMP Mon Dec 24 01:32:58 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: 1) software related to graphic stack: xorg/wayland and gnome-shell/mutter for example. 2) since you have an nvidia card, did you try to change settings in nvidia-panel?

Comment: @mattia.b89 1) It's the one that in stock Ubuntu 18.04 LTS's if I'm not wrong. (tried lightdm too) 2) no I tried to get work the Intel first. Nvidia is my second priority on this setup. Cuz I already have it on Windows

Comment: Can you try with nvidia? In this way we can exclude a driver issue

Comment: @mattia.b89 I setup my Nvidia card with Prime functionality. Prime functionality and Nvidia card is fine tested both by a benchmark program. I can see I actually have 120hz functionality but gnome3 window movings are not smooth as 120hz, Its laggy most of the time. I updated the post.  see the **click to see the usage** linked image. When I move a window, both Intel's cpu and Nvidia's Gpu usage is jumping (cpu from 20 to 100, gpu from 0 to 12)

Answer (score -1):

I too had 120Hz set in my display settings, but the actual refresh rate was 60Hz since I could still notice the blurry motion of my cursor. I did the following: 
Nvidia X server settings -> PRIME profiles -> Turned on NVIDIA (Adaptive Mode) 
For some reason, I had by default the performance mode turned on and this was somehow interfering with my refresh rate.